# Using slice() to extract segments of array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains 12 records. When i slice 4 elements from it. I shows me the sliced value, but when i slice the same array again it doesn't work for me.

```
var arraySliced = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,h]
var Array1 = this.arraySliced.slice(0,4);
var Array2 = this.arraySliced.slice(4,4);
var Array3 = this.arraySliced.slice(8,4);
```

Array1 getting value:- a,b,c,d, but not getting value in array 2 and 3

Comment: How can it work at all? `.slice` is an array method, and you're using it on an object. `{}.slice ---> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: Edited as its completely unrelated to the angular tag

Comment: A quick look into the [`Array.prototype.slice` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) would have answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning an object instead of array(as your requirement), I replaced array

Seccond you are using slice function incorrectly, the actual `slice` function defination is,

`array.slice(start, end)`

Try below code snippat ,

```js
 var arraySliced = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','h']
    var Array1 = this.arraySliced.slice(0,4);
    var Array2 = this.arraySliced.slice(5,7);
    var Array3 = this.arraySliced.slice(8,11);
    
    console.log(Array1);
    console.log(Array2);
    console.log(Array3);
```

Answer (score 2):

> slice(start_number, end_number)

- `var Array2 = this.arraySliced.slice(4,4);`

  => Will not give any element because it doesn't get any number as per syntax.
  If you want you can `arraySliced.slice(4,5);` will gives output `["e"]`
- `arraySliced.slice(8,4)`

  => Start  number can't be greater than end number

Answer (score 0):

The following function shows you what goes on when slicing up the array.

You need to state the block size and have the function figure out the number of blocks. The rest is just doing the slicing for you.

The underflow is just a safeguard, JavaScript does not care if your end index goes out of the array bounds.

```js
var originalArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l' ];
var arraySlices = partitionArray(originalArray, 4);

console.log(arraySlices);

function partitionArray(arr, blockSize) {
  var partitions = [],
      numBlocks  = Math.ceil(arr.length / blockSize),
      underflow  = numBlocks * blockSize - arr.length;
  for (var index = 0; index < numBlocks; index++) {
    var startIndex = index * blockSize,
        endIndex   = startIndex + blockSize - (index === numBlocks - 1 ? underflow : 0);
    partitions.push(arr.slice(startIndex, endIndex));
  }
  return partitions;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to remember when using `.slice()`.

As noted above, and in the docs: `.slice(startNumber, endNumber)`
Both of the parameters are optional.

REMEMBER start counting from Zero.

`var Array0 = arraySliced(); // copies the entire array`
`var Array1 = arraySliced(0,4); // [a,b,c,d]`

REMEMBER the endNumber tells JS where to stop counting BUT DOSEN'T include the endNumber element. 
startNumber IS included in the resulting array.

So, your `.slice(4,4)`, says to start counting at element index=4 (but the 5th element: e) and stop counting at the same element, but not include it, so basically this results in an empty array.

`.slice(8,4)` also results in the creation of an empty array.

Finally, if you want to count from the end of the array, use negative numbers:
`.slice(-4); // [i,j,k,h]`